# Qlik line chat expression

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table like this

| Month | Customer Name | Paid | Collected | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 100 | 1000 | 10% |
| 2 | John Smith | 200 | 1050 | 19% |
| 3 | John Smith | 300 | 1100 | 27% |
| 1 | Kirk Polly | 250 | 1150 | 22% |
| 2 | Kirk Polly | 355 | 1200 | 30% |
| 3 | Kirk Polly | 865 | 1250 | 69% |

The actual column is calculated by Collected divided by Paid. What i want to do is identify the max month so int examples is 3 for both customers and then use the collected amount for the max month and use that value to  divide by the paid for each month. So month 1 for John Smith would be 300/1100 month 2 would be 200/1100   Any idea how i can do this in a line chart where i plot the calculated actual using the month and customer name as dimensions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The calculation should be in the script or in the UI?

Comment: Ideally directly in the UI i.e as an expression in the line chart

Answer (score 1):

The annotated code below will perform the calculation it in the script. Once reloaded the result table will look like:

[image: FinalData]

Ill check if calculation in the UI is possible

```
RawData:
Load * inline [
Month,  Customer Name, Paid,    Collected,  Actual
1    ,  John Smith   , 100 ,    1000     ,  10%
2    ,  John Smith   , 200 ,    1050     ,  19%
3    ,  John Smith   , 300 ,    1100     ,  27%
1    ,  Kirk Polly   , 250 ,    1150     ,  22%
2    ,  Kirk Polly   , 355 ,    1200     ,  30%
3    ,  Kirk Polly   , 865 ,    1250     ,  69%
];

// Find the max month for each [Customer Name]
MaxMonth:
Load 
  max(Month)      as Month,
  [Customer Name]
Resident
  RawData
Group By
  [Customer Name]
;

// left join the RawData to get the Collected amount
// for the max month
// name the field MaxMonthCollected
left join 

Load 
  Month,
  [Customer Name],
  Collected      as MaxMonthCollected
Resident
  RawData
;

// join the resulted table (MaxMonth) back to RawData table
// this way agains each row we'll have the max Collected amount
// (based on the [Customer Name]
join (RawData)

Load 
  [Customer Name],
  MaxMonthCollected
Resident 
  MaxMonth
;

// We dont need this table anymore
Drop Table MaxMonth;

// Calculate "Paid / MaxMonthCollected" and name the field "Result"
// at this point the next steps might not be needed
// we have the "MaxMonthCollected" field in "RawData" table so
// we can perform the calculation in UI expression
FinalData:
Load 
  *,
  Paid / MaxMonthCollected as Result
Resident
  RawData
;

Drop Table RawData;
Drop Field MaxMonthCollected; // MaxCollected can be dropped if not needed
```

**UPDATE**

Something like the expression below can be used directly in the table.

**Bit of a warning. Its a heavy calculation! Running it against large dataset can/will lead to performance issues!**

```
sum(Paid) 
/
aggr( nodistinct
      Sum( {$< Month={"$(=aggr(Max(Month), [Customer Name]))"} > } Collected),
      [Customer Name]
)
```

[image: UI expression]

Comment: Thank you so  much! Is there no way to do this directly as an expression?

Comment: updated my answer with possible expression solution